# Avoiding many "../include" in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I just started getting into CMake with C++ and was wondering how other programmers avoid having to do "../include" in all their `CMakeFiles.txt`.

One example is here: https://github.com/clab/cnn/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt

They create an executable for each example without having to call  `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...)`.

I tried adding the headers when calling `ADD_LIBRARY(...)`, but that didn't seem to work.

Example:

tl/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(SRCS "x1.cpp" "x2.cpp")
SET(HDRS "../include/tl/x1.h" "../include/tl/x2.h")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("../include")
ADD_LIBRARY(test_lib ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
```

tl/CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(TEST_LIB VERSION 0.1)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
```

tl/examples/CMakeLists.txt:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("../include")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(e1 e1.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(e1 test_lib)
```

Edit: I believe that INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...) is only necessary one per each directory throughout the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` command at the top level. No need to explicitly add included files then.

tl/CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(TEST_LIB VERSION 0.1)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("include")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("examples")
```

tl/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(test_lib "x1.cpp" "x2.cpp")
```

tl/examples/CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(e1 e1.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(e1 test_lib)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in a project of mine:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC
    engine/*.cpp
    platfoorm/*.cpp
    )

file(GLOB_RECURSE INCLUDES 
    engine/*.h
    platform/*.h
    )
```

This generate an internal "hardcoded" list of files that the generated makefil will use, so if you add a new source file you will need to re-run cmake.
Of course you can change and add paths, the one in the example are the one I used in my project.

Comment: Why glob includes? The whole point of explicitly adding them is so that changes are autodetected.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by auto-detected, can you elaborate a little about that please?Anyway I was using the include variables to do some nasty copying around.

Comment: Don't bother adding the includes and your build will work fine too. Globbing in general is not recommended, because you need to rerun cmake when changing files. The reason people add includes to targets is so that they are tracked for any changes to the source in the include files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I guess though for source file globbing is fine? Or is it there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? **tl/CMakeLists.txt**

```
SET(SRCS "x1.cpp" "x2.cpp")
SET(HDRS "../include/tl/x1.h" "../include/tl/x2.h")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}/include")
ADD_LIBRARY(test_lib ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
```

You do not need to add headers to `ADD_LIBRARY` or `ADD_EXECUTABLE` if you want to compile your programs and libs. Only source files "cpp,c,cxx,..." are required because through the include macro `#include` you tell the compiler where it finds the header files.

With `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...)` you only add a search path to the compiler where to look for headers. If you have your headers in the same directory as your source you don't need another search path. Also subpaths with include macro like this `#include "../../include"` is possible. So it really depends on the structure of your source files. Also remember, compiler settings setups know where some of the system headers are found. That is why you also do not need to define them.

And last but not least there are cmake scripts and pkg search files where adding paths to specific libraries is done automatically.